# vuetify data table progress indicator

Tags: datatable, material-design, vuetify.js

So the linear progress indicator doesn't work as stated in the Google Material Design documentation. It comes in as it's own table row, which pushes the tbody down 7px. This is a jarring experience. It should come in as shown in my example (taken from the MD docs).

What's the best way to fix this in the code?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qturu.gif)